# Simple scrapy XML spider syntax error

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

I was just trying to make a simple spider using scrapy to grab data from an XML file. This is what I came up with:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider

class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
     name = 'testproject'
     allowed_domains = ['www.w3schools.com']
     start_urls = ['http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml']
     itertag = 'note'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
         to = node.select('to/text()').extract()
         from = node.select('from/text()').extract()
         heading  = node.select('heading/text()').extract()
         body  = node.select('body/text()').extract()

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
         log.msg('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s' % (self.itertag, ''.join(node.extract())))

        item = Item()
         item['to'] = node.select('to').extract()
         item['from'] = node.select('from').extract()
         item['heading'] = node.select('heading').extract()
         item['body'] = node.select('body').extract()
         return item
```

This is the data set:
 http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml

When I try and run it, it unfortunately doesn't work. I think it's related to how I am mapping the tags. This is the error:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>                                                    
    sys.exit(execute())                                                                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute                 
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)                                              
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help          
    func(*a, **kw)                                                                                      
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command            
    cmd.run(args, opts)                                                                                 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run               
    crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()                                                     
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in create_crawler           
    self.crawlers[name] = Crawler(self.settings)                                                        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 25, in __init__                 
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)                                                         
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 35, in from_crawler       
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)                                                            
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 31, in from_settings      
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))                                                      
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 22, in __init__           
    for module in walk_modules(name):                                                                   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules          
    submod = import_module(fullpath)                                                                    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module                            
    __import__(name)                                                                                    
  File "/var/www/spider/crawler/spiders/jobsite.py", line 11                                            
    from = node.select('from/text()').extract()                                                         
         ^                                                                                              
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **from** is a built-in keyword, like `from ... import ...`. change the name to something else will work

Comment: @eLRuLL If my code was working I wouldn't be here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change word *from* to something different, in python it is a keyword.